# how to connect objects with splines with animation nodes?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, splines

I have a group of objects all with keyframed movement. I want to a create splines between the closest objects as they move like this...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9MvcCXsHHY

I know you can connect particles like this...

[image]

but dont know how to do the same effect with a group of objects.

Comment: Wouldn't replacing the vertices locations with the object's locations be sufficient? Have you tried that?

Comment: could you explain what nodes to use exactly? I am lost when it comes to AN

Comment: Add your objects to a group, use the *Objects From Group* node to get the object, use the *Transformation Input* node to get the vertices locations.

Comment: Would you please write up the solution, post it as an answer, then accept your answer please? (You can answer your own questions). That way others can benefit from the answer and others do not come here trying to answer the question when it is solved. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your objects to a group or a collection. Then get the objects using the *Collection Info* node or the *Objects From Group* node. Finally, get their locations using the *Object Transforms Input* node. We now have the points locations, we use the *Find Close Points* and *Splines From Edges* node to create the splines as follows:

[image: Node Tree]